# Code to create a new folder

Tags: c#, .net

I want a new folder to be created when the user clicks a button.While executing when i click the button,it pops up an error message "**Empty filename is not legal**".I want to create the folder in d: drive and it has sufficient space.Can anyone tell where is the problem ?

The code is given below:

```
        string pathString2 = @"D:\Top-Level Folder\SubFolder";



        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString2);



        pathString2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString2, "Mynewfile.txt");
```

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: Based upon the information you've provided so far, the problem is probably somewhere in your code.

Comment: Try with \  instead of /

Comment: Fixed your title since this was about folders, not "file handling", and had nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: @MichaelRodrigues the problem persists even after changing the slash sign.

Comment: Please do not modify your question in way that makes it useless to others.

Comment: @ Erno de Weerd I have used very simple language to ask my question.Where is the ambiguity in my question.Kindly tell me.I am new to this forum as well as to C#.

Comment: Kindly comment in context to the question and be constructive in your criticism so that I can know where am I going wrong exactly.

Comment: You have removed the relevant portion of your question. You now ask _"How to create a folder"_, which is dead simple: use `Directory.Create()`. You seem to have written some code that raises an exception. Do you want that code to work? Then put it back and show what it does and what you have tried. In its current form, this is not a real question.

Comment: @CodeCaster,thank you for your advice.I have edited the question.I have put the error message in bold font.The code snippet given is what I tried out.I hope that addresses your demand.

Comment: On which line do you get the error, and what is the _exact_ exception message?

Comment: The code above is working fine here. This is not the problem. Your problem lies somewhere else: please show that code as well...

Comment: @CodeCaster I wrote the above code in button click event handler function.Then I debugged it.It showed the form with the button.I clicked the button and then it showed error box which said "Empty filename is not legal" There was no exception being thrown in this case.

Comment: Debugging is not clicking the Play button in Visual Studio. Debugging is putting breakpoints, stepping through the code to check the flow and inspecting variables. "Empty filename is not legal" is not a .NET error, it is something your code returns. You do not show the code that does so.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the Folder

D:/Top-Level Folder/SubFolder

and trying to put the file in

D:/Top-Level Folder/SubFolder2

Looks like the problem to me.

Comment: If he is indeed using System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString2);, this is not the case. But it does make me wonder if this is the actual code being used (why create pathString?). Edit: Ninja'd...

Comment: @ JustDaN please be precise in your comment.What exactly do you want to suggest ?

Comment: @Subrat You may wan't to post the full code. I would hazard a guess and say that you are using pathString when trying to create the file instead of pathString2. You may wan't to post the complete relevant code as you will get an answer instead of assumptions.

Comment: Have you stepped thru this in the debugger? I have been know to run different code than I think I ad running before and found the problem this way. Likewise, put the result into strings before calling File.IO functions so you can inspect them to be exactly as you expect.

Comment: Well,I want to create a folder by the name "Top-Level Folder" and in that I want to create another folder by the name "SubFolder2".How can I do that? Please tell me.

Comment: @Subrat: if the above has not yet answered your question, then you should not have accepted it yet.

Comment: @GaryWalker you are right.I got the error message after I clicked on Debug button.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I accepted it because it gave me a suggestion on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, but has it led you to a solution?

Comment: So, it's not yet time to accept an answer. You should accept the answer that solves your problem, not answers that only go part way towards solving your problem.

Comment: Is the information provided sufficient for you all to answer to my question or should I explain it in more detail?

Comment: You need to set break-points in you code so you get example values, etc. while stepping thru the code -- you are trying to figure out why your code is not working, lots of time it is very clear when you examine variable values while debugging to make sure you really understand what your code is doing.